# How to use the number returned by a formula like the 'i' variable in my loop in the Flow Builder?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

In the Opportunity object there are two custom fields called 'start_date__c' and 'stop_date__c'

I have a requirement where I need to create a flow that executes when the the Opportunity stage is Closed Won (this will be an autolauched flow executed with process builder) and create N amount of Ocupation__c records (it has a lookup to the Opportunity object) based on the difference between 'start_date__c' and 'stop_date__c' in the parent opportunity object.

So for example if 'start_date__c' = 2021-01-20 and 'stop_date__c' = 2021-01-22 the difference will be of 2 so I need to create two Ocupation__c objects.

---

I flow builder I've created a new variable resource of type formula that looks like this:

[image]

this formula is returning a Number (wich is the one that tells me how many days is the difference between the two dates)

Then I need to execute the flow, get the parent Opportunity record, loop over this formula returning the number and create one Ocupation__c record until the number returned by the formula is equal to 0

This is the theory .... but in the flow builder I'm not being able to do it and I don't know how to achieve this.

Any help would be more than valuable.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- You don't need a process builder.
- You can build a record-triggered flow (after save) and loop in that flow.
- Here is an example on my Youtube channel: https://youtu.be/Y9AA5ke-5cw
- If you are available, I will run a free training session covering loops this Tuesday. Find out here (recording will be posted on the Youtube channel above): https://superpeer.com/utkan

Comment: I don't think the solution in your flow will work as he wants to iterate through a loop for 1 Opportunity record to create n Occupation records based on the number of days between two date fields on the opportunity. I've been trying to work out a solution but it is messy with the flow loop as we don't have a way of doing a simple for loop based on a parameter in flow.

Comment: Exactly .... the mess is in the Loop for creating the Occupation records. I will check out your videos but I don't think you understood my problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: I can only speak to what I understood, Yes. But I think this is doable based on my understanding.